# How to best handle email and password authentication with Firebase - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, keychain

I have a log in page with three buttons:  `logInOutlet, logOutOutlet, bookingsOutlet`.
If user is logged in, show logOut and bookings, and hide logIn. Conversely, if user is logged out, hide: logOut button & bookings button, show: logIn button.
Basing on the log in status of the current user, I would like to show/hide certain buttons.

- 1. Initially, I thought about checking if the current user has an .uid value ( it means the user is logged in), otherwise, if `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil`, then user is not logged in and execute some action.
     It turns out I was wrong because `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid` will always return a valid uid value even if the user is logged out.
     "The Firebase authentication session is persisted on the user's device in the iOS keychain." - I don't know much about keychain data persistence.
- 2. Another option would be to save the .uid in NSUserDefaults when user is logged in. 
     If user logs out, remove the key/value pair from NSUserDefaults. Next, when I stop the app in the simulator (goes in background mode), the log in session is no longer valid, so when app is launched again in foreground mode, in viewDidLoad I should check if  a key/value pair exists in NSUserDefaults for .uid value and if there is, execute an action to log the user in and show/hide certain buttons.

I would like to know if there is a better way to keep the logIn session active until the user hits the `logOutOutlet` button. I have to mention that the user can log in from different viewControllers across the app. The initial assumption I explained at point 1 seemed like a viable option since Firebase would always handle most of the work.

```
 @IBAction func logOut(sender: AnyObject) {

    // if the current user is logged in, try to log out and 
    // hide: logOut button & bookings button
    // show: logIn button
  //  if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid != nil {

        do {
            try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
             print("the current user id is \(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)")
        }

        self.logInOutlet.hidden = false
        self.logOutOutlet.hidden = true
        self.bookingsOutlet.hidden = true

       // FullData.finalemailAddress = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email
        FullData.finalemailAddress = nil

    } // end of if.. FIRAuth.auth()

}


   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // if the user is logged out
    // hide: logOut button & bookings button
    // show: logIn button
     // if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil {

        self.logInOutlet.hidden = false
        self.logOutOutlet.hidden = true
        self.bookingsOutlet.hidden = true


        // if the user is logged in
        // hide: logIn Button
        // show: logOut button & bookings button
    } else if

        //FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid != nil{

        self.logInOutlet.hidden = true
        self.logOutOutlet.hidden = false
        self.bookingsOutlet.hidden = false

        print("Great \(FullData.finalemailAddress)")
        print("Super \(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)")
    }

}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you have a problem with the UI i.e. checking if a user is logged in and then hide/show stuff or do you want to do something with the login session? _I would like to know if there is a better way to keep the logIn session active_ Firebase handles the session for you. At least I specifically don't have a problem with that on my app

Comment: @tech4242  I want the logged in user to stay logged in all the time, even when the app goes in the background, and based on the login/log out status, I will perform certain actions such as show/hide certain buttons on the UI or attempt to retrieve information from Firebase Real Time Database.   How do you do it in your app? Do you store the email/uid in NSUserDefaults and based on that, in viewDidLoad show/hide login/logout button?

Comment: I check if the user is logged in in AppDelegate and then I present either my app VC or my login VC as the root VC. You are using only one VC right? That's much easier. I am using `FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in ... }` in my AppDelegate to check for the user

Comment: @tech4242        I allow the user to log in both from a slide out menu (SwRevealViewController class) and at some other place across the app while placing an order. On firebase.com, it shows that I can check if the user is logged in without adding a state listener  by calling the synchronous authData function [OLD_Docs](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c2570a70e1cf8fd6ab8e07feee4e6938) , but I can't find the new version in the [New_Docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios) . Have they removed it?

Comment: @tech4242      Should I use if FIRAuth.auth()  != nil  instead of if authData != nil?

Comment: Well I am using FIRAuth.auth() because it is in the new Firebase docs and it serves its purpose - being async and all. I haven't used authData so unfortunately I can't help you with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121976/discussion-between-bogdan-barbulescu-and-tech4242).